# Display an easing effect when the site opens

Tags: css

How can i display a easing effect, opening from the left, when the page is open? Like this site: http://focuslabllc.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would use CSS transitions. Take a look at the example I've created http://jsfiddle.net/ZL9m7/1/

Relative CSS is simple as

```
.container {
    opacity: 0.1;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear; /* Play with timing functions */
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.container-ease-in {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And tiny javascript trigger (jQuery for convinience):

```
$(function() {
    $('.container').addClass('container-ease-in');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like in dfsq-answer the animation will be triggered with a class by js (this time without jquery):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oElement = document.getElementById('content');
    oElement.className = oElement.className + ' start_animation';
};
```

And the css changes the margin and the opacity with transition(-duration):

```
#content {
    ...
    /* starting status */
    margin: 10px 200px 10px 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    /* now set the animation duration */
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
}

#content.start_animation {
    margin: 10px 100px;     /* change horizontal margins */
    opacity: 1;             /* change opacity            */
}
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rB2yW/).

Answer (score 1):

This is the fella who wrote the js for the site you're referencing. I played with CSS as an option for this but ended up just going with jQuery 100%. I'll have a blog post soon about some of the dev aspects of our new site facelift and I'll talk about how we did that. It will inclue some jsFiddle demos etc.

Comment: It's hard to get a more official answer than this :).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your content initially (with CSS) and then, once the page content is loaded, use javascript to trigger/run an easing operation to make things visible.

Or, you can start with no content and build the page content with javascript in a way that reveals it with the easing you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery animation or YUI transition to achieve this. Hide the div and show it OR set the width to 0 and then animate it to maximum with a specific duration.